# VPN problems in OS X El Capitan with Parallels 11 installed

Tags: macos, vpn, parallels, osx-el-capitan

This problem occurred in the el capitan beta, but only after I've installed Parallels 11. However it might be just an unlucky timing and maybe a new update for el capitan caused it.

The problem: I can't access the VPN normally. When connected via WiFi I can't even ping any host reachable through the VPN. the service order is in short:

- WiFi
- VPN
- Parallels

I've never changed anything about this service order (didn't even know of it's existence until few hours ago). After changing it and putting VPN to the top:

- VPN
- WiFi
- Parallels

I can access the servers normally, however, internet is damn slow, because all my traffic goes through the VPN. Interestingly, out of all the possible combinations to arrange those 3 the following one also works:

- Parallels
- VPN
- WiFi

So VPN doesn't need to be top priority, it just needs to be before WiFi. However, I don't want this, I want to be able to use the internet normally, without going through the VPN for normal traffic and only use the VPN to access the internal servers.